# i want to drag multiple images and drop them in a particular area in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am making a kids game where I have alphabets on top and random images down.When i drag an image such as apple to letter 'a' it should have a pop up saying its right. Can anyone guide me how to go about this idea???

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is:

1. Draggable views inside a layout
2. Collision algorithm
3. QuickAction Dialog or an Invisble Dialog (for the popup)

1.

```
public void setDraggable(final View view)
{
    final LayoutParams lp1 ;
    lp1 = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    final int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    final int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            view.bringToFront();
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
            {
                break;
            }
            case(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
            {
                if((event.getRawX()+(view.getWidth()/2))<width&&((event.getRawX()+(view.getWidth()/2)) > view.getWidth()))
                    lp1.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - (view.getWidth()/2);
                if((event.getRawY()-view.getHeight())<height&&(event.getRawY()-view.getHeight())>0)
                    lp1.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - view.getHeight();           
                view.setLayoutParams(lp1);
                break;
            }
            case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
            {
            }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });     
}
```

basically what it does is change the margin of your view so it looks like it's moving. Use a relative layout here

2.)  I'll just give you a hint here. all views/images inside an App is rectangular so just get all sides(in pixels) of your view then use if-else statements.

3.) http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/
or you can simply use setVisibility